# How to run Ansible tasks as a specific user

Tags: ruby, ansible

Part of the Ansible playbook I'm currently writing involves creating a new user as root, installing `rvm` for that specific user, then switching to them in order to run `rvm`. It doesn't seem to take, however. Here's what I'm currently running.

```
---
- name: Install pexpect
  yum:
    name: pexpect
    state: latest
- name: Create rvm group
  group:
    name: rvm
    state: present
- name: Create rvmuser
  user:
    name: rvmuser
    state: present
    group: rvm
    password: "{{vault_rvm_password}}"
- name: Download signing key
  shell: "command curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg2 --import -"
  become: True
  become_user: rvmuser
- name: RVM single-user install
  shell: "curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable"
  become: True
  become_user: rvmuser
- name: Install Ruby
  shell: "rvm install 2.2.1"
  become: True
  become_user: rvmuser
```

(These particular shell steps appear to be the preferred way of installing a specific version of Ruby; I tried using `yum` to install an RPM, but then `gem` fails.)

Basically, when it gets to the "Install Ruby" step, it fails because it can't find `rvm`, which is a strong indication that it's still trying to run the command as root. Here's the error:

```
TASK [ruby : Install Ruby] *****************************************************
fatal: [10.121.250.21]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "rvm install 2.2.1", "delta": "0:00:00.007545", "end": "2017-04-12 16:14:35.974732", "failed": true, "rc": 127, "start": "2017-04-12 16:14:35.967187", "stderr": "/bin/sh: rvm: command not found", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

Am I doing this incorrectly, or is something else going wrong behind the scenes?

EDIT: The user is being created correctly, I've confirmed. After running the top five steps, I can SSH into the machine, switch to `rvmuser` and see that `which rvm` returns a path.

Comment: what was the fix for this? I have the same problem right now. Can you help me sharing your solution, please?

Comment: @alexventuraio the expected answer solved the issue I'm having (along with the comments below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a path issue, i.e. the newly created `rvmuser` does not have `rvm` in its `$PATH`:

Try full path to `rvm` in this task:

```
- name: Install Ruby
  shell: "rvm install 2.2.1"
  become: True
  become_user: rvmuser
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case. If I manually SSH into the machine and switch to rvmuser, `which rvm` succeeds. The directory it's located in turns up in the `PATH` variable, as well.

Comment: Ansible does not use a login shell when it transfers modules and executes them, thats why its not picking up the `$PATH` of the `rvm` user. You can either run `rvm` with full path or source the env in a shell task: pseudocode `- shell: . /etc/environment && commandhere`

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. This seems to have done the trick! Now I need to figure out expect. Thanks!